# Android google maps api v2 its blank on device and shows on emulator

Tags: android, google-maps, device

like the title says I'm using **google maps api v2** and it works on my **avd** but not on my real device (on my device its just blank)

I found many questions on this same topic but none of those were helpful to my case

any ideas? oh I almost forgot when I run it with the emulator the only error that I get its

> "failed to find provider info for com.google.settings"

I already tried with getting a new api key, keystone, uninstalling the app from my device before installing it again... dont know what else.

thank you for at least reading this

**EDIT:**    Im using a Lg g2 dont know if it helps

**EDIT2:**  Manifest, mapa.java and xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="Login.cyclingcenter"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >



<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ViBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
     <activity 
        android:name="Swipe"


        ></activity>
    <activity
        android:name="Login"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Goolge Maps API Key -->
    <meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
     android:value="AIzaSyBtOk02dBY98C7S8BILmMyLLkMbUh8-jLs" />
    <meta-data 
     android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
   android:value="6171000" />


</application>
```

```
package Login.cyclingcenter;

import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;



public class Mapa extends Fragment {

MapView mMapView;
private GoogleMap googleMap;


@Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View mapa = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

    mMapView = (MapView) mapa.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     establecerMap();       

    return mapa;


}  


public void establecerMap(){
   if(googleMap==null){

       googleMap = mMapView.getMap();
       }
   else{
     //configuración mapa

       configuraMap();
}
}  
public void configuraMap(){
 //vista normal, puede ser satelite e hibrido
   googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

   //establezco mi posicion en el mapa
   googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

// Asigno un nivel de zoom
   CameraUpdate ZoomCam = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14);
   googleMap.animateCamera(ZoomCam);

// Establezco un listener para ver cuando cambio de posicion
   googleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
       public void onMyLocationChange(Location pos) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           // Extraigo la Lat y Lon del Listener
           double lat = pos.getLatitude();
           double lon = pos.getLongitude();

           // Muevo la camara a mi posicion
           CameraUpdate cam = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(
                   lat, lon));

           googleMap.moveCamera(cam);}});
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
   super.onResume();
   mMapView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
   super.onPause();
   mMapView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
   super.onDestroy();
   mMapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory(){
   super.onLowMemory();
   mMapView.onLowMemory();
}





}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:apiKey="AIzaSyBtOk02dBY98C7S8BILmMyLLkMbUh8-jLs"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and it was that Google uses an api key for debug and one for release and since I was using my own device it is consider as a release even though I'm just testing (google doesnt know that haha), that's it its just another key.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, your app is using needed permissions? Like this:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Following [this basic guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start).

If your app working on AVD but not on device - this can be reason.